# Is eating mushrooms allowed in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, food

mushrooms are neither fruit nor vegetables They are a special type of fungus

source :http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/health-fitness/healthy-eating/are-mushrooms-good-you?page=all

but are they allowed to be eaten (halal)?

is there any fatwa/hadith related specifically with mushrooms ?

both Shia and Sunni views are welcome

note: i know everything which is not haram is by default allowed and also know that it is permitted to eat food containing microbes/bacteria(pro biotic like curd )

Comment: I believe your own note answered the question.

Comment: @system down , yes i know the general ruling, but looking for fatwa (if there is any) specifically for mushrooms as this is a new kind of food discovered

Comment: Mushrooms aren't new. Arabs have known about desert truffles since antiquity.

Comment: Are you referring to edible mushrooms found in a variety of foods, or are you referring to magic mushrooms which are intoxicating, poisonous and cause hallucinations?

Comment: yes i am talking about edible mashrooms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned it, the base is everything is halal unless it is stated by Qur'an and Sunnah it is haram. After you read the following from the Qur'an and Sunnah, I advise to refer to this [website](http://www.guidedways.com/halalfoodguide.php) to get more details about subtypes of foods.

[image: Maeda 5:3]

Translation

> Prohibited to you are dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and
>   that which has been dedicated to other than Allah , and [those
>   animals] killed by strangling or by a violent blow or by a head-long
>   fall or by the goring of horns, and those from which a wild animal has
>   eaten, except what you [are able to] slaughter [before its death], and
>   those which are sacrificed on stone altars, and [prohibited is] that
>   you seek decision through divining arrows. That is grave disobedience.
>   This day those who disbelieve have despaired of [defeating] your
>   religion; so fear them not, but fear Me. This day I have perfected for
>   you your religion and completed My favor upon you and have approved
>   for you Islam as religion. But whoever is forced by severe hunger with
>   no inclination to sin - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

And the Sunnah,

> “Halal (the Lawful & Permissible) is clear and Haram (the Unlawful &
>   Impermissible) is clear. Between halal and haram lays some doubtful
>   things. Many people do not know whether it is permissible or not.
>   Whoever leaves out these doubtful things in order to protect his
>   religion and honor, then he is safe. Whoever indulges in these
>   doubtful things/matters it is very possible that he will fall into
>   haram, similar to a person who grazes his animals near the royal
>   pasture it is very possible that one day he will graze in the royal
>   pasture. Behold! Every king has a royal pasture and the royal pasture
>   of Allah is those things which have been made impermissible.”
>   (Tirmidhi 1205)

Sayyiduna Abu Hurayrah (radhiallahu anhu) narrates that the Prophet (salallahu alaihi wasallam) said: “Allah the Almighty is pure and accepts only that which is pure. Allah (swt) has commanded the faithful to do that which he commanded the Messengers, and the Almighty has said: “O Messengers! Eat of the pure things and do right”. And Allah the Almighty has said: “O you who believe! Eat of the pure things We have provided you.”, then Rasulullah (salallahu alaihi wasallam) mentioned (the case of) a man traveling on a long ardous journey, greatly troubled and distressed, with disheveled hair crying to Allah swt, O my Lord! O my Lord! But, his food is haram, his drink is haram, his dress is haram and he is nourished with haram. How then his du’a be accepted (Muslim 1015)

Sayyiduna Abu Hurayrah (radhiallahu anhu) reports that the Prophet (salallahu alaihi wasallam) said, “A time will come upon the people wherein a man will not bother what he intakes; whether from a halal source or haram.”  (Bukhari 2059)

The Prophet (salallahu alaihi wa sallam) said, “Avoid whatever you have doubts about in favor of what is not (doubtful).” (Tirmidhi)

Sayyiduna Ka`b Ibn Ujrah (radhiallahu anhu) relates that the Prophet (salallahu alaihi wasallam) said, “A body nourished with haram will not enter Jannah”. (Tirmidhi 614)

Sayyiduna S'ad (radhiallahu anhu) relates that the Prophet (salallahu alaihi was sallam) said “O S'ad purify your food (and as a result) you will become one whose supplications are accepted. I swear by Him in whose hands the soul of Muhammad lies, verily a servant (of Allah) tosses a haram (impermissible) food morsel in his stomach (due to which) no good deed is accepted from him for 40 days” (Tabrani 6395)

Comment: so the jist is "mashrooms are allowed" am i right ?

Comment: Yes, mushroom in general is Halal

Comment: ok, then i am accepting your answer as i did not get any answer against it !

Comment: I will ask an idiotic question. But what about poisonous mushrooms? Where it is forbidden? Source please.

Answer (score 0):

I note that mushrooms are halal.
The edible varieties taste great, are nutritious and contain healthy ingredients.
However great care must be taken when collecting wild mushrooms as some varieties are poisonous and can lead to a painful death.

Comment: This is true, but it would be better if you had some sources.

Answer (score -3):

Eating mushroom is not only halal but it's a food liked by our prophet s.a.w. (p.b.u.h): Eating button mushrooms (that is, white mushrooms or table mushrooms) is sunnah and is great for eyes.

Comment: can you please provide reference of it being sunnah .