# Is it permissible for a husband to seek another spouse during a breakdown in his marriage?

Tags: nikah, talaq

Imagine the following scenario:

Husband and wife get married. Things do not work out no matter what methods are used for resolution. 
Before seeking Talaq and divorce in the country, is the husband allowed to perform a search to finding another potential spouse for him (and then doing a Talaq on the existing wife)?

Morally/ethically to me it would be better to have a clean break and then start the search however there could be some "time" involved where the husband searches for another spouse but cannot find anyone therefore still "goes back" to the existing wife to try and work things out again even though they may have tried before but did not succeed.

Where does Islam stand on this matter?

Comment: Seeing how a man doesn't need anyone's permission to marry, not even that of his current wives, why wouldn't it be permissible?

Comment: I am asking from Islam's perspective.

Comment: G.Bach is commenting based on islams perspective. However i'm quite sure that the other spouses should know about a new marriage as today it is much easier to have another wife in a different country.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.