# Can a couple consummate their marriage outside the home?

Tags: nikah, sex, relationships

I don't mean outdoors where they can be seen by someone else, but perhaps in a hotel or something like that. For example, they may go out to dinner at a restaurant, and stay the night at a hotel. Would this be allowed? All views with supported evidence appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.