# Is it haram to use a persona online?

Tags: halal-haram, internet

I want to start a new account that doesn't reveal my name for privacy purposes. In that case, can I use a generic name?

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.