# Are Muslims allowed to research/read/listen about sex related content (not porn)

Tags: halal-haram, sex

For examples can Muslims read human sexuality research papers,  sex advice, and listen to sex education related podcasts regardless if their married or not. If they are married are they then allowed to use what they have learned with their partner. If they are not married can they research for preparation of married life, while obviously not acting upon the urges.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be allowed?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I recall reading somewhere that one should protect there eyes and ears from anything sexual. Perhaps in a Hadith.

Comment: Yeah and? Why scholars such as ibn Hazm and others have been writing books on this topic? Why scholars consider a healthy sexual life as an important part for a working conjugal life? Why in fiqh we discuss the topic of the penis penetrating the vagina and the consequences in from the perspective of marriage, relationshup, tahara etc.? Would you close your ears when listening to this topic? In that case you would sin because you rejected an important knowledge for your daily life!

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.