# Is pasta halal to eat?

Tags: halal-haram, food

My aunt bought Casino Torti brand pasta for me to cook.  I have searched all over the internet about this brand but I did not find anything. This brand is not in the lists of non-halal food (Australia website - which I don't remember), but I still want to know is it true or not.

I know the ingredients of pasta is just durum wheat and eggs (on the label), but I want to be sure on this.

Comment: If wheat and eggs are the only two ingredients, both of which are trivially known to be halal, what exactly is causing you doubt?

Comment: The basic rule is that food is halal. Haram is the exception. As for you, not finding it in any non-halal food websites should indicate that it is halal. Especially if it only contains wheat and egg, since that is halal.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its halal. If its just eggs and wheat, no problem! Cook away! Enjoy your pasta. :)

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.