# Can i change and add to my full name?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, naming

Assalamualaikum,
 I have a question regarding my name. When I was very young my parents separated as my father and mother had an arranged marriage and he was very violent and abusive physically. I have never known my father and dont even know what he looks like, also he has no contact with me and has never bothered to contact us with any sort of help.
 His name is  Ali Darr . My name was Yusuf Ali at birth.
 Would I be able to add a middle name to my name? Would it be possible to change my name to Yusuf Deen Darr. 
 ***The reason i am asking this is because it has a physiological impact on me when i see or hear my fathers name because of his past and what he has done to my mother. So changing my name to my fathers first name doesnt remind me of it AS MUCH*** .  
The reason for the addition of the middle name is so that when i go to work etc i can ask them to call me by the preferred name of Yusuf Deen, is this permissible? And lastly would it be allowed to change all my legal documents, passport, driving licence, bank details etc to Yusuf Deen Darr?

I hope i can get an answer soon as its been on my mind for a long time.

Jazakallah Khayr

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.