# Is magic in video games haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sihr

Just light stuff like Mario or Pokemon or something along those lines. I want to be able to play these games but I'm not sure if it falls under witchcraft and if it is haram or not.

I know magic like this isn't possible for people to do and the magic talked about in the Quran refers to curses in stuff, but is this also considered haram?

Comment: What makes you think it could be haram?

Comment: Huh, Pokémon it is a haram game, because it kills you. Have you heard news about what happened when a Chinese teacher was walking on the street playing Pokémon, and then she got hit by a car? That’s how dangerous it is. Well, that depends on what Pokémon are you talking about, either Pokémon normal or Pokémon Go, but Pokémon Go is a clean suicide.

Comment: @AlexA "Pokémon it is a haram game, because it kills you. Have you heard news about what happened when a Chinese teacher was walking on the street playing Pokémon, and then she got hit by a car? That’s how dangerous it is." By that logic, reading a book regardless of content is haram because if you get distracted by it, you can be careless enough to get run over in traffic. That's not a valid fiqh argument.

Comment: @G.Bach ...., Why not?

Comment: @AlexA Because reading books is halal, the only potentially haram bit is the gross negligence of reading books **while in traffic**.

Comment: @G.Bach Yeah, well, I referring to this sentence you said”That’s not a valid fiqh argument”.

Comment: @AlexA That's what it is about. I'm saying this: if what you said about Pokemon was a valid fiqh argument, then it would apply to books as well and they would be haram to read. No scholar ever has issued a fatwa banning the reading of books regardless of content, to the best of my knowledge; therefore, the argument does not work on books, and so it cannot work for Pokemon either. If Pokemon is haram, it must be because of some argument other than "you can get run over if you play the game while you are in traffic".

Comment: Well, while you play it is, but as for reading there is no problem, because you increased your knowledge.

Comment: @AlexA If you’re a Muslim; I advise you to quit being so comfortable in labeling what is forbidden. You don’t understand the magnitude of this act.  - Have you heard the news that people choke on food? Is food Haram now? Such a bad argument. Learn to refrain yourself from labeling such matters, no matter how “small” they may be, wether it’s Pokémon or Salat. You are talking in place of God himself.

Comment: @Shadi Alright then, I’ll stop. I thought it is like that because I heard many bad stories about it.

Comment: @Shadi And by the way, I don’t speak in God’s place and I’ll never will speak in His place.

Comment: @Shadi And of course, I’m a Muslim

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)

Answer (score -1):

The magic that Islam talks about includes curses and spells to hurt others or any other bad intentions. Probably u know what I mean.

Showing tricks is NOT magic. It's just a well-made trick which secret can be revealed, So it's not the magic that uses Jin, devils or spirits to achieve the goal.  People who use Jinn and devils are considered as (Outlaws) they are out of Islam.

Computer games don't use spells or devil. Mario is not even a magic!. it's just a graphic game

**computer games are not magic.**

Comment: I think the question is about magic in video games, not whether video games are themselves magic. For example, RPGs that have people in then that can use magic.

Comment: Spirits? I thought the spirits stay on their graves till the Day of Judgment and only those who are good can visit each other’s grave and they don’t need to visit beyond cimintery according to Islamic point of view.