# Is it haram to normally wear immodest clothing at home and in front of my husband?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

I normally wear short clothes, see-through clothes, tight clothes, lingerie, only undershirt, and even sometimes not even a bra when wearing see-through clothes (can see my breast and nipples) and when he is home I wear the same clothes.

Is my clothing haram?

Because I don’t wear modest clothing in my house and in front of my husband, and will I get punished for that?

Comment: Your clothing in front of your husband is what ever he likes to see you wearing, but once foreigners are involved you should cover yourself, as you shouldn't present your body as a ware for the sight of non-Mahrams.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)

Answer (score 0):

From what you have stated, there is absolutely nothing "Punishable" about your home clothing (If you could even call it that). As-long as your husband is the only person seeing you in this state, man, or woman, there is nothing "punishable" about your stay-at-home dress. Just make sure you cover the windows so nobody looks at you when almost completely nude.

Answer (score -3):

My dear sister in islam....
watever u wear infront of your husband is completely fine...but remember, women in islam are refered to as diamonds and in the Quran theyre refered to as Covered gems to the closest tafseer, so why would you want to show your body to others apart from your husband!? 
consider it baseless as who else would you want to impress besides him!?
And really no one would really be interested as much as your husband would be to look at wat u wear...for others itll just be another girl on the street.....so for Allahs sake, obey Allahs laws as he says to cover yourself, 'women should be covered' to the nearest translation in surah AlAhzab...fear Allah as indeed he is Severe in punishment.
May Allah help you to overcome your desires in order to please him.
Forgive me for any mistakes I may have said... and indeed Allah knows best.