# Can the translated Quran and the Arabic Quran be read in a clean place outside?

Tags: quran, quran-translation

As Salam Aleikhum, I want to know for my reference Can the translated Quran and the al Quran be read in a clean place outside is it allowed and permissible with respect for Quran. jazakhum allahu khairan.

Comment: There should be no reason why not. Only prohibited places are either restrooms or places where there is _najas_.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.