# is it haram to make money off of video games?

Tags: halal-haram, money, business

to be clear, I follow the opinion that playing video games is permissible, so please don't lecture me on that. I have wanted to start streaming on twitch(a live game thing), and making videos on youtube after college and university.I am aware that it takes a pretty long time for your videos to get monetized and stuff, but what I want to know is if making videos of games like Minecraft, csgo, and trials fusion is haram. I do intend to give money to charity.

Comment: If "playing video games is permissible", then why would making money off videos of them be impermissible?

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)