# Can we look at pictures of the deceased?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, death, photos

I’ve always been told that we can’t have pictures of the deceased or look at those pictures once they have passed away. Is that true in my anyway? Will they get punished because of us viewing their pictures? Can I have some Islamic evidence for this (if possible) either from the Quran or authentic hadiths jazakallah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure there is an evidence about that topic because old people didn’t have camera or something. But actually islam depends on logic. People get punished if they do something bad or forbidden in islam. Your doings cant effect the people passed away.