# Is it Haram to work online?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

Many people is working on internet working website by sitting in home on computer they earn money  . Is it Haram or halal to work on internet ?

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, the Internet is just a tool for conducting business. We can explain this with an analogy: when construction workers sit inside a construction machine, they are controlling the machine to do their labor, instead of the workers doing the labor themselves.

Going back to your question and relating it to the analogy, the Internet is simply the ‘construction machine’ which is a tool being used for earning money. There’s nothing in Islam that I know of that prevents us from using tools to earn a living. So overall using the internet to earn money from a halal source is perfectly halal.

Now, what exactly they do online is what will determine if the income is haram or halal. If they’re selling halal merchandise online, or investing in halal companies (like stocks) through the Internet, then this is perfectly halal.

HOWEVER, if they’re using the Internet to engage in haram activities like gambling, then this income will be haram.