# Are eggs, milk, and other animal products that do not require slaughter halal?

Tags: halal-haram

If you don't have to kill the animal, is it halal? I am confused by this. I do not want to cook something if it is not. also, Is cage free organic halal? I have not seen anything in particular on the egg cartons from the brand I use.

Comment: This is a clear duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838/13438.

Answer (score 1):

Eggs and Milk are halal, as long as they are from a halal animal (chicken, cow etc.) and not taken from it after its death (other than from Islamic slaughter).

**Reference:-**

> #### إن خرج البيض من حيوان مأكول في حال حياته، أو بعد تذكيته شرعا، أو بعد موته، وهو مما لا يحتاج إلى التذكية كالسمك، فبيضه مأكول إجماعا، إلا إذا فسد
>
> #### إن خرج اللبن من حيوان حي فهو تابع للحمه في إباحة التناول وكراهته وتحريمه. ويستثنى من المحرم: الآدمي، فلبنه مباح، وإن كان لحمه محرما، لأن تحريمه للتكريم لا للاستخباث. وعلى هذا اتفق الحنفية والمالكية والشافعية والحنابلة
>
> <sup>— [**الموسوعة الفقهية**](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-11430#page-2929)</sup>