# During Kissing Hajr-e-Aswad men and women got touch with one another is it halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram

Men and women durning kissing Hajr e Aswad collide with one an other is it halal or haram?

Comment: Why should it be haram? (See [ask] and [Is X halal reference-question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.5453)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a woman intentionally touched by a men who is na mehram to her is haram. but when you are at such a holy place how can you touch any body with intentions?
So they touched by each other unintentionally it's not haram in this case.