# Regarding Wearing Smart Band

Tags: halal-haram, men-women

I use a smart fitness band.But I heard that if anything is such like womens' is prohibited. Band somewhat like a band but I use it not for fashion I use it for my fitness info and as a watch.
Does smart band is allowed for men in this case ?

Comment: Does it have gold-plated components?

Comment: No, It feels like rubber .

Comment: This looks to me as a [Is "X" halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.2594) question.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally fine if it isn't made for woman.
Most of the bands are unisex (for men and woman). So there is no issues in wearing it.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be an issue as long as it's not designed for women.

Comment: But It can be used by anyone.

Comment: @babiker Most smart bands are unisex

Answer (score 0):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

So wearing a fitness band is like wearing a watch. That is something both men and women wear. The band would not resemble a bracelet since there is a digital display. Furthermore, wearing it is meant for health tracking purposes. Not meant to be sign of beauty for others to see.

I hope you a good day!