# Is Netflix subscription halal?

Tags: halal-haram, tv

Netflix provides funding for shows like [Big Mouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Mouth_(TV_series)), [Super Drags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Drags) and [Messiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messiah_(American_TV_series)).

It also purchases licensees for movies and shows that contain [sexual themes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Girls_Wanted), [alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hangover), [gambling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakegurui_(2017_TV_series)), and many other unislamic themes.

Is it okay to support Netflix financially?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question) Netflix might also offer other content why should it be haram to use?

Comment: I know that Netflix funds and licenses other content, such as children movies, animations, and educational documentaries. A portion of the revenue would go to halal content, and another would go to haram content. Is it okay to give your money to Netflix if you know that they may use it to display haram content on their platform?

Comment: I've seen Islamic banks block payments to this service specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum...
First of all I want to tell you that I'm not an Islamic Aalim, leader or mufti. So, I will try to give my best answer according to my point of view. 
As you all know *Netflix is a platform where you can watch various types of movies, web series and other types of contents which are mostly or maybe totally Haram contents for public. That's why simply according to me, uses of Netflix in any way is completely Haram.

(Note: This is my personal *Opinion so, please meet your Reliable Aalim too conformation)
Thanks to Read:

Answer (score 0):

If you went to a nightclub and donate money to sport and help improve its quality and expand there financ.
Well this be haram?

If yes the same gose to Netflix your helping them make more movies and shows that dose not please God and by helping them with a subscription your a partner in the bad deeds so if other people watch watch something that dose not please Allah you get part of the bad deeds.

If no get some help

Comment: We really appreciate your answer but please try to bring some evidence omti your answer, you can also check [answer] for more information