# Is it okay to pray for relationship break?

Tags: allah

When I was 15 I used to like an actor.But he was in a relationship.Then I prayed for his break up which happened.Now I am 19, I regret for doing such a horrible thing.Will  the same thing happen to me?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question)

Comment: How would you know that Allah actually answered your prayer, if he knows it was spoken in jealousy? Break ups can just happen, don't assume you are the one that caused it.