# Are you allowed to collect bank intrest in a video game?

Tags: riba, game

If it is Haram or Halal whats the reasoning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> “And for their taking interest even though it was forbidden for them, and their wrongful appropriation of other people’s property. We have prepared for those among them who reject faith a grievous punishment” (4:161)

**No** type of interest is halal in Islam.

It is said that eating interest is equivalent to going to war against Allah and His Rasul (saws)