# Is making anime review haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Here's a question. If someone makes anime review on YouTube or discussing about anime. Anime have haram elements like music and so on. But the one who makes review doesn't add any music to his video. And if he makes money from those review will it be considered as haram or halal?

Comment: Well don't you have to watch anime to do reviews on it??? Think about it in this sense

Comment: I want to know whether doing it halal or haram. Not to know whether the person will get sin by watching anime. These two are different things

Comment: Look at this question, then I think you can edit your response to me: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question. For example: if using your phone while driving is illegal, then isn't playing a game on your phone while driving illegal as well?