# Can I use same shaving machine for beard and private hair?

Tags: hair, shaving

Assalam o alaikum,

I find it convenient to use shaving machine to remove my private hair. Now, my question is, can use the same machine for my public hair as well?

Jazak-Allah,

Comment: its recommended not to shave the beard. why do you think it cannot be used?.

Comment: This question is from the category [is "X" halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|68.6676).