# Is studying astronomy haram?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

I wanted to know is studying astronomy haram? And by astronomy I mean studying of planets, stars and galaxies and how they are made and what things are there in it and etc. I am not believing in any kind of shirk or astrology like stars decide what happens here etc. I don't believe in those, will it still be haram?

Comment: Astro**nomy** is not Astro**logy**. Why would it be haram? See [Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in studying astronomy and in your question it's mentioned that astrology is not your concern, so  I don't see any real question here unless you provide further details as to why you think astronomy is Haram.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

> In Western astronomy, most of the accepted star names are Arabic, a few are Greek and some are of unknown origin. Typically only bright stars have names.
> — [List of Arabic star names - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arabic_star_names)

During Europe's "dark ages", it was Muslim scholars and scientists that continued the development of mathematics and sciences such as astronomy.
The word "astronomy" means to name the stars, and most of those names are Arabic (or Anglicized forms thereof).

Similarly, the English word "Chemistry" comes from "Alchemy", which is a corruption of the Arabic "al-kīmiyāʾ" (ﺎﻠﻜﻴﻤﻳﺍﺀ).
It too came from a Greek word, but it demonstrates that modern science largely came to us via the Muslim world.

Answer (score 0):

Astronomy - the study of space is not haram. Islam encourages man to observe and study nature.

Astrology - using the movement of the stars to "predict" the future is haram