# recording camera in home

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sin, sunnah

Assalamualaikum my question is is it Halal or Haram for a Muslim to have a security camera inside of his home or a doorbell that takes a picture of every time you walk by to open the door is that Haram

Comment: Why would it be haram? Questions like this are required to reasonably demonstrate why they do not fall into the basic ruling: [Is X halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question)