# Is War Thunder (video game) haram? In this game you play as a war vehicle at war

Tags: halal-haram, game

Im worried because I have been playing this. and also is Minecraft haram?

Comment: As salam. Form the good old days of Linux: Linux$ wargames
Would you like to play a game? y
A strange game.
The only winning move is
not to play.
Linux$

Comment: The "comment" function doesn't preserve newlines, but everyone can easily guess where they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam Alaikoum, all praise be to Allah,

There are many fatawas regarding video games such as [this one](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2898/are-video-games-haram) which should answer your question and rules that video games are permissible unless they interfere in your capacity to proceed with your obligatory duties, I am unaware of the intricaties of such video games. All is halal until proven to be haram, refer to [this meta post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36838/is-x-halal-reference-question).

And Allah (swt) knows best.

Comment: Assalamu-Alaikum brother, thank you for your answer ,it was very helpful. regarding video games interferring with obligatory duties, is no problem for me because I pray salat 5 times a day and read the Quran at least once a day. About the game, It is a war vehicle game where you can fight in batles against other online players (playing as vehicles) I am aware that as long as you dont have the intention of actually going to war, it should be halal. Please inform me if you think there are any issues.